# How to pass Kendo grid selected row values from View to controller

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

Looking for sample code to pass selected row of Grid values from View to Controller.
I need to pass first five columns of 1st row of Grid to the controller. I am able to pass
one value from view to controller but I am unable to pass the details of other columns.

Comment: can you share your controller method signature and your code where you are getting the data from the grid.

Comment: I tried like this Public JsonResult GetDetailsById ([DataSourceRequest] DatasourceRequest request)

Comment: My JQuery :-     
#(document).ready (function () {
$('#btnDelete').click(function () {

var gview = $('#Grid').data("kendoGrid");

var selectedItem = gview.dataItem(gview.select());

if (selectedItem == null)
{

alert("Please select one record

");

}
var id = selectedItem .id;


$.get("/EMP/SaveRecord", {id: id, name: 'Success'}, function (data) {
alert(JSON.stringfy(data));
});

});

});

Answer (score 0):

The below code can be used to get the selected row data and collect them for posting to the API controller

```
var entityDataGrid = $("#divId").data("kendoGrid");
var rows = entityDataGrid.select();
let rowData = [];
rows.each(function(index, row) {
    var selectedItem = entityDataGrid.dataItem(row);
    rowData.push(selectedItem)
});
//pass on the rowData to your controller which should accept a collection of items
```